# Query for RAMDirectory for 6 GB Index File

Tags: apache-spark, lucene

I am writing a spark job, where use case if of millions of documents doing search on Lucene index for getting details.

The index is around 6 GB and contains around 40 million docs.Now I can't use elastic search as doing a batch search is getting bottlenecked. I used HDFS Directory for search and performance is bad.

I was thinking of creating g a RAMDirectory index searcher per executor.

I see following warning in the code :

> **Warning**: This class is not intended to work with huge indexes. Everything beyond several hundred megabytes will waste resources (GC cycles), because it uses an internal buffer size of 1024 bytes, producing millions of byte[1024] arrays. This class is optimized for small memory-resident indexes. It also has bad concurrency on multithreaded environments.

My search is not simple(Use more like this and other term queries) which cannot be mimicked by spark SQL.

My question is has anybody used ram directory over Gb of file to see. My index will be read-only, so maybe I won't hit this issue.

If not how to solve this?

Comment: I'm pretty confident in saying that this is simply not a feasible solution to your performance problems. You should, instead, take a look at how you are structuring your documents, and what sort of queries you are using.

Comment: I know. My Documents are simple documents with 5 text fields and there is no nesting. The queries I have seen are morelikethis on one field and simple term queries